# Python remove everything in bytestring before certain character

Tags: python, string, substring, byte, strip

I have the following bytestring
`b'removethis\x00\x002020.10.14\x00\xf2\x00^\n\x84>\x01\x00\x10\x01\x14\x00\x00\x00\x8d\xec\xdc0\x1bo\xe7\x15^\n\x84>\x01\x00\x10\x01\x04\x9b_\x18'`

i want everything before the first `\x00` removed so the substring `removethis` gets removed basically.

So the problem is that i only want everything before the first `\x00` to get removed not any future `\x00`'s that may come in the string and im not sure how to do this.

Comment: `after the first ...` is a typo, I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a regex for this.

```
import re

txt = "b'removethis\x00\x002020.10.14\x00\xf2\x00^\n\x84>\x01\x00\x10\x01\x14\x00\x00\x00\x8d\xec\xdc0\x1bo\xe7\x15^\n\x84>\x01\x00\x10\x01\x04\x9b_\x18'"
x = re.search("\\x00.*", txt)
print(x)
```

Here we find the first occurance of `\x00` and then take everything to the end of the string as well using `.*`. The result is your string minus 'removethis'

Comment: how could i turn it into a bytestring again?, this requires the bytestring "txt" to be in quotes which just turns it into a string.

Comment: @Emil B You can bring it back to bytes using `txt_in_bytes_again = bytes(txt, 'utf-8')`

Comment: it returns a format like this <re.Match object; span=(12, 39), match=b'\x00\x002020.10.14\x00\xf2\x00p\xe1E?\x01\x00\x1> not a string

Comment: @EmilB you can get the matched text from the regex result by calling `x.group(0)` which is the entire matched text